# How do I map a get operation in an array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, hash, ruby-on-rails-5, iteration

I'm using Rails 5.  I have an array of hashes, each with an "id" key.  I want to get a corresponding array of just the values of each hash's ID.  I tried this

```
[14] pry(main)> arr_of_hashes = [{:id => "abc"}, {:id => "cdef"}, {:id => "123"}]
=> [{:id=>"abc"}, {:id=>"cdef"}, {:id=>"123"}]
[15] pry(main)> arr_of_hashes.map(&:id)
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for {:id=>"abc"}:Hash
```

but as you can see, it's complaining about the "map".  What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Don't kick yourself:

```
arr_of_hashes = [{:id => "abc"}, {:id => "cdef"}, {:id => "123"}]
ids = arr_of_hashes.map { |hash| hash[:id] } 
puts ids # ["abc", "cdef", "123"]
```

The way you were using `map` expected a method: `map(&:method)`